# Gstremer Events

Tags: events, gstreamer

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how events work in Gstreamer. I understand that you can pass events to elements from the application to end a stream or block a pad etc., but when I look at the sample code in [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html#section-dynamic-changing), it seems like the program is not sending any specific event, just listening them through probes. If the program is only listening events through probes, then these events have to be sent between elements in some kind of fashion after certain things automatically. However, I couldn't find any information regarding to this. How does the events work in Gstreamer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information on the design of gstreamer events can be found here (https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/docs/random/events). This document describes how the various events propagate through a pipeline.

In the provided sample code, an EOS event is sent to an element with the function : 
 `gst_pad_send_event (sinkpad, gst_event_new_eos ());`
The element then proceeds to flush all of its buffers and forwards the EOS event downstream to the next element by posting the event on its src pad. This event continues through the elements until it reaches the installed probe which contains special logic to manipulate the pipeline if an EOS event is received.

This sample shows several things in regards to your question:
 - Events are intrinsically handled within the gstreamer pipeline. The gstreamer elements automatically handle them.
 - Pad Probes can be used to externally observe/modify events as they propagate through the pipeline.
 - Events can be directly inserted within a pipeline using the function `gst_pad_send_event` or `gst_element_send_event`

Comment: however, in the sample code I posted the link about, I can't see when an event message is sent? Thats my question really, when and why does the elements send event messages between each other? Do they do this automatically or the user has to send a message specifically all the times?

Comment: Events can be sent by either the elements themselves (_automatically_), or by a user. If you're really interested in seeing every event that is posted, you could set gstreamer's log level to debug and look though the output logs. However, it is probably easier to place several pad probes on elements and view the events that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its just a bit annoying that it doesn't write anywhere that they are also sent automatically by the elements themselves. Also the stuff in the link were good, thanks a lot.